# Responsive mixin not working with nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm having a play around with nuxt.js and trying to build a simple website to see how everything goes together. I've got some scss files that are all included in the component but my mixin isn't working.

UPDATE i've added the style resources to my nuxt config but now get error
No mixin named mobilefirst in /pages/index.vue

My template code is below, I have imported my mixins file and tried to use my `@include mobilefirst` mixin but when the page is rendered is only output the first bits of the rule and ignores anything my mixin.

```
<template>
  <div>

    <navigation />

    <hero />

    <qualifications />

     <section class="about">
        <div class="container container--900">

            <h2 class="about__title">
                JJ And Sons Plastering 
            </h2>

            <p class="about__text">
            JJ and Sons are a family run business that have been leading providers in all aspects of plastering for over 18 years. 
            We are based in Yorkshire and carry out work throughout the whole of the UK with a reputation for delivering a high end flawless finish.
            </p>

        </div>
    </section>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navigation from '~/components/Navigation.vue'
import Hero from '~/components/Hero.vue'
import Qualifications from '~/components/Qualifications.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Navigation,
    Hero,
    Qualifications
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss"> 
@import '../assets/scss/helpers/variables.scss';
@import '../assets/scss/helpers/mixins.scss';

.about {
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;

    @include mobilefirst(em(991)) {
        padding: 75px 0;
    }

    @include mobilefirst(em(1024)) {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }

    @include mobilefirst(em(1400)) {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }
}

.about__title {
    @include font-sizes(25, 25, 40, 55, 55);
    @include lineheight(30, 30, 50, 65, 65);
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.about__text {
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: light;
}
</style>
```

My nuxt.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  */
  head: {
    title: 'jjandsonsplastering',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'JJ & Sons Plastering website' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      {
        rel: 'stylesheet',
        href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,700|Roboto:400,500,700'
      }
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Customize the progress bar color
  */
  loading: { color: '#3B8070' },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  */
  build: {
    styleResources: {
      options: {
        // See https://github.com/yenshih/style-resources-loader#options
        globOptions: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/scss/*/*.scss')
      }
    },
    /*
    ** Run ESLint on save
    */
    extend (config, { isDev, isClient }) {
      if (isDev && isClient) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          enforce: 'pre',
          test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
          loader: 'eslint-loader',
          exclude: /(node_modules)/
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build#styleresources

Comment: @Aldarund I added that to my config and the file is been loaded correctly but now i'm getting ``` No mixin named mobilefirst in /pages/index.vue (line 50, column 14)```

Comment: styleResources: {
      scss: './assets/scss/*/*.scss'
    },